# AVPlayer how can I find out how long it will take before it is ready to play?

Tags: objective-c, buffer, loading, avplayer

I am sure there here to be a way to do this but I can't seem to find it. I am getting closer but maybe someone already has the answer.

I am streaming audio via AVPlayer and sometimes the initial load time can be anywhere from 3 to 12 seconds. I have the player automatically start playing when I get the KVO that it is AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay but I am trying to estimate how long that is going to be and have a progress bar for it.

Some items I have found so far;

-The loaded time ranges only has one item in the array at the start that grows with a start time of 0.0 and grows to a 1 to 4 second buffer

-when the buffer gets to a certain size, the "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" gets triggered and right after AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay happens.

Basically, how can I figure out what AVPlayer decides is the minimum buffer size to start playing?

Answer (score 0):

Spoke with an apple evangelist for AVPlayer and he says there is currently no way to do this. There is no easy way to know the progress and/or how long it will take before it starts to play. He suggested creating an apple bug to see if they can add that feature. (bugreport.apple.com 23824785)